# Program that prompts the size of array then add all numbers not at the edge

Tags: java, arrays, addition

How can I make a program that prompts the size of an array and fill it with random numbers, and then add all the numbers that are not at the edge?

Heres the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class array {

    int matrizNN[][];
    public void setMatrizNN(int n){

        matrizNN = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrizNN.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrizNN[i].length; j++) {
                    matrizNN[i][j]= (int)(Math.random()*10);
                    System.out.print(" "+matrizNN[i][j]);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you write out an expected output with a given n? And what have you tried so far for adding the interior numbers?

Comment: for example 6 and i cant add the numbers that are on the edge, por example the row (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)  and the las one like(x,0) (x,1)(x,2)(x,3)(x,4)(x,5) dont add and also (0,0)(1,0)(2,0)(3,0)(4,0)(5,0) and the last column x=6

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an idea of how to fill `matrizNN[][]`. To add the non-edge values up, you can use a similar set of `for` loops but with the first and last values omitted. Here's the basic idea:

```
int centerTotal = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < matrizNN.length - 1; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j < matrizNN[i].length - 1; j++) {
          centerTotal += matrizNN[i][j];
     }
}

System.out.println(centerTotal);
```

Comment: @DominicBedard Do you need any additional help or clarification?  If this answer is helpful then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class array {

int matrizNN[][];
public void setMatrizNN(int n){

    matrizNN = new int[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrizNN.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrizNN[i].length; j++) {
                matrizNN[i][j]= (int)(Math.random()*10);
                System.out.print(" "+matrizNN[i][j]);
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("Size "+matrizNN.Length);

}
```

}

Comment: Isn't this just a copy of the code in the answer? Printing the length doesn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void setMatrizNN(int n){

        matrizNN = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrizNN.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrizNN[i].length; j++) {
                    matrizNN[i][j]= (int)(Math.random()*10);
                    System.out.print(" "+matrizNN[i][j]);
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        } 
        int sum=0;
        System.out.println("=========================");
        for (int i = 1; i < matrizNN.length-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < matrizNN[i].length-1; j++) {
                //System.out.print(matrizNN[i][j]);
              sum+=matrizNN[i][j];
       }
    }
        System.out.println("sum is :"+sum);
    }
```

If you havent find the solution yet here is the code. Hope this is what you want.